# Setting a Name for a PSDrive in Powershell

Tags: powershell, drive

when I create a PSDrive it usually just gets the name of the location it points to. "Being dom-loc-Share (G:)"

```
New-PSDrive -Description "Group-Drive" –Name "G" –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\dom\dfs\dom-loc-Share" –Persist | Out-Null
```

[image: Screen]

I named mine "Bob" now by clicking the name and changing it. However every PSDrive I create now is called Bob

This is curious but not the real issue (though if someone cared to explain). 
My question is: How do I set the name i.e. bob in my script?

I tried

```
Get-PsDrive G
```

and checked the properties, but was not able to set the displayed name in the windows explorer.

How would I set this name instead of bob to "Group-Drive" upon creation of the PSDrive?

If I try Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume I get the following result...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, though if anyone knows a better approach to it, feel free to tell me.

```
$DNsplit = ((Get-ADUser ([Environment]::UserName)).DistinguishedName).split(",")
$STO = $DNsplit[$DNsplit.count -5].Substring(3,3)
$MyRoot = "\\dom\dfs\dom-$Sto-Share"
$RegPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2"
if(Test-Path $MyRoot)
{
    if(Get-PSDrive | ?{$_.Name -eq "G"}) 
    {
        Remove-PSDrive G
    }
    New-PSDrive –Name G –PSProvider FileSystem –Root $MyRoot –Persist -Scope Global | Out-Null 
    $a = Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2"
    foreach($Key in $a)
    {
        $CompKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\$($MyRoot.Replace('\','#'))"
        if($Key.Name -eq $CompKey)
        {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $key.PSPath -Name "_LabelFromReg" -Value "Group-Drive"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this:

```
$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'g:'"

Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{Label="Bob"}
```

side note:

using `Set-WmiInstance` is usefull because it can change more than one parameter at a time; example:

```
Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="Q:"; Label="NewLabel"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however - the drive G does not exist if I do Get-WmiObject. Just a System-Reserved Drive, D and C . So the variable $drive in your code is sadly for me empty.

Comment: @Asharon You have a strange behaviour, if I can *see* a drive letter ready in explore I surely can *see* it using `get-wmiobject win32_volume`. Maybe try running the powershell console *as administrator*

Comment: Hi, I edited my post to show another picture. Maybe you can take a look?

Comment: I found this in the registry, maybe the only way to change it is by editing this value?
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\##dom#dfs#dom-loc-Share`
**Value name:** _LabelFromReg
**Value data:** bob

Comment: My code works well in all computer I've used.  Try modifying registry.

Comment: I would think it has to do with it being a PSDrive - is it possible that they are handled differently? If you make a new-psdrive G will it show up in get-wmiobject for you?